# Viewing Storage Space allocation for physical disk

Tags: powershell, storage-spaces

I have a server that had four disks (2x 4TB and 2x 3TB drives) in a Server 2012 R2 Storage Pool. There are two virtual disks in the pool - a parity disk and a mirrored disk.

The idea was to add two more 4TB disks, retire the mismatched 3TB drives and then extend the storage pools capacity to use the extra space of the 4x 4TB disks.

I have added the two extra 4TB drives, and have removed one of the 3TB drives from the pool succesfully. However on attempting to remove the final 3TB drive, I'm told that there is not enough spare drives in the pool to keep the pool online. Huh?

So when I go to look at the space used on each disk, what I see doesn't seem to make any sense to me:

[image]

Somehow all 5 of the disks in the server are currently allocated, and their allocation amounts (judging by the "free space" column) just don't make any sense.

I expected to see the 3TB disk fully allocated, three 4TB disks with 3TB allocated and 1TB free, and one 4TB disk with nothing allocated at all. But what I'm actually seeing is all over the place.

Is there any way to see how a specific disk has been allocated? i.e. I'd like to run a command on `PhysicalDisk2` to find out why it only has 6.75GB of unallocated space.